# Preventing from loading referenced tabels in datagrid

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've a problem when populating datagrid in WAF with one of my tables from database.
In my database I've created few tables which are referencing to one specific column (Id_Exhibit).

During populating of my datagrid with desired table everything looks good, but other referenced tables populate it as well.

Simply after all columns that I've chosen populate with its data from specific table in database, there appear another ones with the names of tables that are referencing to the Id_Exhibit column...

How can I prevent them from loading into datagrid?

there is not much in my code, just one method for populating datagrid

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MuzeumGUI
{
    public partial class Exhibits: Form
    {

        public Exhibits()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Ehxibits_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PopulateDataGridView();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        void PopulateDataGridView()
        {
            using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities())
            {
                dgvExhibits.DataSource = db.DBExhibit.ToList();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

As for the class generated from my created entity, Exhibit looks like this:

```
namespace MuzeumGUI
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class DBExhibit
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public DBExhibit()
        {
            this.DBRenovation = new HashSet<DBRenovation >();
            this.DBReservation= new HashSet<DBReservation>();
            this.DBRental= new HashSet<DBRental>();
        }

        public int Id_Exhibit { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string Era{ get; set; }
        public string Description{ get; set; }
        public string Creator{ get; set; }
        public string Type{ get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Year { get; set; }
        public string Century { get; set; }
        public string Style { get; set; }
        public string Status{ get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public ICollection<DBRenovation> DBRenovation{ get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public ICollection<DBReservation> DBReservation{ get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public ICollection<DBRental> DBRental{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: first you need to post some code so we will be able to understand better what you are trying to do.

Comment: @YairI I've added some code. Maybe this will bring closer what I was trying to achieve :).

Comment: I've also removed public before all ICollection<>... and it worked, but somehow i feel that it's going to get me into trouble, later on, when I move forward with this project...

Comment: try to put this "db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;" before this row "dgvExhibits.DataSource = db.DBExhibit.ToList();" it should prevent layze loading.